# C# Improving bitmap image quality

Tags: c#, printing, bitmap

I have a c# form that takes a bitmap of the contents of a panel and prints that image. This panel is made up of labels and graphics. When I print the bitmap of the panel but the print out is pixilated. Is there a way of print the image more clearly or at a high quality as Microsoft word would? Or is there any alternative way to go about this. Thanks

```
    private void PrintNotes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintPreviewDialog ppd = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
        doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(doc_PrintPage);
        ppd.Document = doc;
        CapturaImage();
        if (ppd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            doc.Print();
    }

    Bitmap image = null;

    void doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
    }

    private void page1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Point startPoint in startList)
        {
            Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen, startPoint, finishList[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }

    private void CapturaImage()
    {
        int width = page1.Width;
        int height = page1.Height;
        image = new Bitmap(width, height);
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        page1.DrawToBitmap(image, rec);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need the image? Why not just render directly to the print context? Then let MS choose the quality. As it is - things are going to depend on the resolution of your image - which is probably 96ppi while the print out is probably (at least) 300dpi. Hence the pixelization

Comment: How would I go about doing this. The labels and graphics have set locations. Will I be able keep these location by doing this.

Comment: Look at the link it works 100%[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813865/save-system-drawing-bitmap-with-high-resolution-aspx)